# how to activate a current tab in angularjs bootstrap javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the below code to activate the current tab selected but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills " id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#A"> A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#B"> B</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#C"> C</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I guess, localStorage function in my code is not working properly . Can any one pleas guide me with the solution.  I am using Angularjs, Bootstrap.

Comment: try like this  $window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your object that you want to store in localstorage. You cannot store objects in localstorage directly. A workaround can be to stringify your object before storing it, and later parse it when you retrieve it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', JSON.Stringify($(e.target).attr('href')));
    });
    var activeTab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeTab'));
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills " id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#A"> A</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#B"> B</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#C"> C</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```